# Error: java.lang.ClassCastException LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast ,when starting app

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

Hello I am struggling with an error when starting my app here is the error log,
I am trying to add a forground service to the app but removing the code for it does not fix the issue , I have tried a fresh install of the app onmy device, clean project, rebuild project, restarting android studio I seriously dont even know where to begin to solve this error

```
E/racticesmartap: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.smartpractice.smartpracticesmartapp, PID: 10481
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.getTargetWidget(ConstraintLayout.java:1144)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:1021)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:803)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1561)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:726)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:726)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:847)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23454)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2954)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1753)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2041)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1636)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7946)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:812)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

I do not know where this error occurs, please help

Comment: You are trying to cast LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout.

Comment: @kzncrda Yes, Thank you how must I start looking for the problem in the XML files?

Comment: the problem is I am unsure where excatly this is happening

Comment: I don't know your XML Layout. But you can import the corresponding layout in LinearLayout.

Comment: thats the problem the logcat does not show WHICH xml is giving the error

Comment: E/racticesmartap: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.smartpractice.smartpracticesmartapp, PID: 10481
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: @kzncrda Thanks for all the help man, The issue was that I made changes to my one layout and then in the background a textview was constrainded to the main constraint layour while it was INSIDE a linear layout, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Thank you, good work. I enter in response. I want you to rate it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cast LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout. But you can import the corresponding layout in LinearLayout.

```
E/racticesmartap: [qarth_debug:] get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail. E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.smartpractice.smartpracticesmartapp, PID: 10481 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams –
```